# Object is undefined when getting it in component

Tags: angular

I'm getting value of my json object course so i can set it on my patchValue. My console log displays the data, but when i try to get it on my component, its saying course_professor is undefined or courseCode. I have also tried to loop through my json object course but when i get the specific, it also displays undefined. How to fix this?

**console.log**

```
{
    "message": "Sucess!",
    "course": {
        "id": 1,
        "courseCode": "test",
        "courseName": "test",
        "courseDescription": "test",
        "course_professor": 2,
        "course_created_by": 2,
        "course_date_created": "2019-10-13T20:19:57.546529Z",
        "course_last_modified": "2019-10-13T20:19:57.546563Z"
    },
    "prof": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "email": "prof@gmail.com",
            "first_name": "Prof",
            "last_name": "Good"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "email": "test@test.com",
            "first_name": "test",
            "last_name": "test"
        }
    ],
    "result": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "class_id": 15,
            "coursemodule_title": " Module 1",
            "coursemodule_date_created": "2019-09-30T09:54:22.109528Z",
            "coursemodule_last_modified": "2019-09-30T09:54:22.109559Z",
            "coursemodule_created_by": 2,
            "coursemodule_course_id": {
                "id": 1,
                "courseCode": "test",
                "courseName": "test",
                "courseDescription": "test",
                "course_professor": 2,
                "course_created_by": 2,
                "course_date_created": "2019-10-13T20:19:57.546529Z",
                "course_last_modified": "2019-10-13T20:19:57.546563Z"
            }
        }
    ] }
```

**component**

```
@Input() course: any = [];

  courseUpdateForm = new FormGroup({
    course_professor: new FormControl(''),
    courseCode: new FormControl(''),
    courseName: new FormControl(''),
    courseDescription: new FormControl('')
  });

    constructor(
      private coursemoduleService: CoursemoduleapiService
  ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
   this.courseUpdateForm.patchValue({
        course_professor: this.course.course.course_professor,
        courseCode: this.course.course.courseCode,
        courseName: this.course.course.courseName,
        courseDescription: this.course.course.courseDescription
    })

    }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    this.courseUpdateForm.patchValue({
        course_professor: this.course.course.course_professor,
        courseCode: this.course.course.courseCode,
        courseName: this.course.course.courseName,
        courseDescription: this.course.course.courseDescription
    })
  }
```

Heres how I am passing my data, pls. refer to this link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eyuccg

Comment: You didn't mention how you're passing this course as an input from the parent component template and how you're fetching the data in the parent component class. Can you please add the code for that too. Or rather create a sample stackblitz replicating the issue?

Comment: If you're getting the data asyncronously then passing it to the `@Input` of the component, the data probably isn't resolved when the component is initialized thus `course: any` is `undefined`.

Comment: @SiddAjmera pls. refer to this link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eyuccg this is just a code on how I am passing my data. App does not work on the link. Thanks!

Comment: This still doesn't have the `app-coursemodule-list` component on it. Please be mindful of the fact that I don't have much idea of your project and it would really help if you could take some time to properly create the stackblitz project with the minimal code required and that also replicates the error that you're getting. That would allow me to focus directly on the issue that you're facing instead of fixing the code first to replicate the issue that you're getting. Hope you understand. :)

Comment: @SiddAjmera I'm trying to pass te details of the course details to form. The object being passed is course as can been seen on json above. So all that its need is the course-list component and and course-form on the stackblitz. Can we have a chat instead. I think it would be easier?

Answer (score 0):

In your CoursemoduleComponent you fetch a list of courses and assign it to the courses variable array. This is local in your component and it's saved. And that's what you see in your log. After that, you redirect to /courses. So you need to pass that data to another component somehow. You can use router params or service for that. Or put it in observable and subscribe to it from another component. But You need to pass courses from your component to a new one.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is I used localstorage to save the id of the object in getting the details. I then insert the id to the details function and tried to get the objects values but still, I'm getting the undefined error. So I used formbuilder instead and used setValue function to have the data on the forms.